# Why wrapping the Data.Binary.Put monad creates a memory leak?

Tags: memory, haskell, memory-leaks, binary, memory-management

I'm trying to wrap the Data.Binary.Put monad into another so that later I can ask it questions like "how many bytes it's going to write" or "what is the current position in file". But even very trivial wraps like:

```
data Writer1M a = Writer1M { write :: P.PutM a }
or
data Writer2M a = Writer2M { write :: (a, P.Put) }
```

create a huge space leak and the program usually crashes (after taking up 4GB of RAM). Here is what I've tried so far:

```
-- This works well and consumes almost no memory.

type Writer = P.Put

writer :: P.Put -> Writer
writer put = put

writeToFile :: String -> Writer -> IO ()
writeToFile path writer = BL.writeFile path (P.runPut writer)
```

```
-- This one will cause memory leak.

data Writer1M a = Writer1M { write :: P.PutM a }

instance Monad Writer1M where
  return a = Writer1M $ return a
  ma >>= f = Writer1M $ (write ma) >>= \a -> write $ f a

type WriterM = Writer1M
type Writer = WriterM ()

writer :: P.Put -> Writer
writer put = Writer1M $ put

writeToFile :: String -> Writer -> IO ()
writeToFile path writer = BL.writeFile path (P.runPut $ write writer)
```

```
-- This one will crash as well with exactly the
-- same memory foot print as Writer1M

data Writer2M a = Writer2M { write :: (a, P.Put) }

instance Monad Writer2M where
  return a = Writer2M $ (a, return ())
  ma >>= f = Writer2M $ (b, p >> p')
                        where (a,p) = write ma
                              (b,p') = write $ f a

type WriterM = Writer2M
type Writer = WriterM ()

writer :: P.Put -> Writer
writer put = Writer2M $ ((), put)

writeToFile :: String -> Writer -> IO ()
writeToFile path writer = BL.writeFile path (P.runPut $ snd $ write writer)
```

I'm new to Haskell and this makes no sence to me, but the wrapper monads seem very trivial so I'm guessing there is something obvious I'm missing.

Thanks for looking.

UPDATE:
Here is a sample code that demonstrates the problem: http://hpaste.org/43400/why_wrapping_the_databinaryp

UPDATE2:
There is also a second part to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019655/why-wrapping-the-data-binary-put-monad-creates-a-memory-leak-part-2).

Comment: What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: After you asked I tried with -O2 (I used none before) but the memory foot print did not change.

Comment: Could you post a trivial test program so others here don't have to build their own?

Comment: Good idea, I'll compile something soon. Can I somehow post it here on stackoverflow or should I use hpaste instead?

Comment: Done, appended a link to a sample program.

Comment: Isn't the problem that by the bind (>>=) in the wrapped version is making a huge thunk. Bind in the "native" Binary.Put monad is using mappend on a Bytestring Builder which I think does some evaluation 'under the hood' rather than build a thunk.

Comment: I've tried your sample and with my GHC 6.12.3 and -O2 flag both versions show almost identical time/space behavior. Replacing `data` in "problematic" wrapper with `newtype` reduces the difference even further. Without -O2 it's definitely memory-greedy. You sure you recompiled with -O2? Try `-O2 -fforce-recomp`

Comment: Ed'ka, I must say I haven't tried the simplified example with -O2. I'm quite sure it didn't make a difference with the 'real' program. I'll double check later today when I'll have both versions at hand.

Comment: Silly silly me! Ed'ka, you were right. Here is what I was doing: I changed the code to make the test, double checked everything, compiled and ran it without the -O2 flag, then compiled and ran again *with* the -O2 flag, saw no difference. But that was because it didn't get compiled the second time because the source hasn't chaged! So the -O2 flag does solve my problem; It might still interesting to know what is happening if -O2 is off though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After poking around for a bit, I found that the problem seems to be the usage of binary's (>>=) to implement (>>). The following addition to the Writer1M monad implementation solves the problem:

```
  m >> k = Writer1M $ write m >> write k
```

Whereas this version still leaks memory:

```
  m >> k = Writer1M $ write m >>= const (write k)
```

Looking at [binary's source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/0.5.0.2/doc/html/src/Data-Binary-Put.html#line-96), (>>) seems to discard the result of the first monad explicitly. Not sure how exactly this prevents the leak, though. My best theory is that GHC otherwise holds onto the PairS object, and the "a" reference leaks because it never gets looked at.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to make the monad more *strict*? Eg. try to make the constructors of your datatyp strict / replace them with a newtype.

I don't know what's the exact problem here, but this is the usual source of leaks.

PS: And try to remove unnecessary lambdas, for instance:

```
  ma >>= f = Writer1M $ (write ma) >=> write . f
```

Comment: Changing from data to newtype is what the good folks at #haskell have suggested as well, unfortunatelly changing that and removing the lambda as you suggested did not change the memory foot print. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Yes, here is the result: http://i.imgur.com/4Q2E3.png , the yellow area appears when I use one of the wrappers.

Comment: Very strange. I think I can't help you.

Comment: I'd guess that the Writer1M is inadvertently acting as a retainer, holding a pointer to the output and thereby preventing the GC from reaping the bytestrings along the way.  Try running with retainer profiling and see if that tells you anything.