# Why wrapping the Data.Binary.Put monad creates a memory leak? (Part 2)

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, binary, monads, monad-transformers

As in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828902/why-wrapping-the-data-binary-put-monad-creates-a-memory-leak), I'm trying to wrap the Data.Binary.Put monad into another monad so that later I can ask it questions like "how many bytes it's going to write" or "what is the current position in file".

Before, I thought that understanding why it leaks memory while using a trivial (IdentityT?) wrapper would lead me to solving my problem. But even though you guys have helped me resolve the problem with the trivial wrapper, wrapping it with something usefull like StateT or WriterT still consumes too much memory (and usually crashes).

For example, this is one way I'm trying to wrap it and which leaks memory for big input:

```
type Out = StateT Integer P.PutM ()

writeToFile :: String -> Out -> IO ()
writeToFile path out = BL.writeFile path $ P.runPut $ do runStateT out 0
                                                         return ()
```

[Here](http://hpaste.org/44036/why_wrapping_the_databinaryp) is a more complete code sample that demonstrates the problem.

What I would like to know is this:

1. What is happending inside the program that causes the memory leak?
2. What can I do to fix it?

For my second question I think I should explain in more details what I intend the data to look on disk: It is basically a tree structure where each node of the tree is represented as an offset table to it's children (plus some additional data). So to calculate offset of n-th children into the offset table I need to know the sizes of children 0 to n-1 plus the current offset (to simplify things, let's say each node has fixed number of childs).

Thanks for looking.

UPDATE:
Thanks to nominolo I can now create a monad that wraps around the Data.Binary.Put, tracks current offset and uses almost no memory. This is done by dropping the use of StateT transformer in favor of a different state threading mechanism that uses Continuations.

Like this:

```
type Offset = Int

newtype MyPut a = MyPut
  { unS :: forall r . (Offset -> a -> P.PutM r) -> Offset -> P.PutM r }

instance Monad MyPut where
  return a = MyPut $ \f s -> f s a
  ma >>= f = MyPut $ \fb s -> unS ma (\s' a -> unS (f a) fb s') s

writeToFile :: String -> MyPut () -> IO ()
writeToFile path put =
  BL.writeFile path $ P.runPut $ peal put >> return ()
  where peal myput = unS myput (\o -> return) 0

getCurrentOffset :: MyPut Int
getCurrentOffset = MyPut $ \f o -> f o o

lift' n ma = MyPut $ \f s -> ma >>= f (s+n)
```

However I still have a problem with tracking how many bytes is MyPut going to write on disk. In particular, I need to have a function with signature like this:

```
getSize :: MyPut a -> MyPut Int
```

or

```
getSize :: MyPut a -> Int
```

My aproach was to wrap the MyPut monad inside WriterT transformer (something like [this](http://hpaste.org/44419/how_do_you_save_a_tree_data_st)). But that started to consume too much memory again. As sclv mentions in comments under nominolos answer, WriterT somehow cancels out the effect of continuations. He also mentions that getting the size should be possible directly from the MyPut monad that I already have, but all my attempts to do so ended in non compilable code or an infinite loop :-|.

Could someone please help further?

Comment: I think your code is using the Lazy version of StateT, try using Control.Monad.State.Strict instead.

Comment: I (not the OP) tried using `.Strict` but it didn't change the space requirements. `C.M.S.Strict` is only marginally stricter than `C.M.S`.  The strictness refers to the returned tuple (recall that `StateT s m a = s -> m (s, a)`).  However, none of the tuple components are necessarily evaluated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the monad transformer is too lazy.  You can create a heap profile (without having to build it specially) by running the program with:

```
$ ./myprog +RTS -hT
$ hp2ps myprog.hp
$ open hp2ps.ps    # Or whichever viewer you have
```

In this case it's not particularly helpful, because it only shows lots of `PAP`s, `FUN_1_0`s and `FUN_2_0`s.  This means the heap is made up of lots of partially applied functions, and functions of one argument and two arguments.  This usually means that something is not evaluated enough.  Monad transformers are somewhat notorious for this.

The workaround is to use a more strict monad transformers using [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).  (his requires `{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}`.

```
newtype MyStateT s m a =
  MyStateT { unMyStateT :: forall r. (s -> a -> m r) -> s -> m r }
```

Continuation passing style means that instead of returning a result directly, we call another function, the *continuation*, with our result, in this case `s` and `a`.  The instance definitions look a bit funny.  To understand it read the link above (Wikipedia).

```
instance Monad m => Monad (MyStateT s m) where
  return x = MyStateT (\k s -> k s x)
  MyStateT f >>= kk = MyStateT (\k s ->
    f (\s' a -> unMyStateT (kk a) k s') s)

runMyStateT :: Monad m => MyStateT s m a -> s -> m (a, s)
runMyStateT (MyStateT f) s0 = f (\s a -> return (a, s)) s0

instance MonadTrans (MyStateT s) where
  lift act = MyStateT (\k s -> do a <- act; k s a)

type Out = MyStateT Integer P.PutM ()
```

Running it now gives constant space (the "maximum residency" bit):

```
$ ./so1 +RTS -s 
begin
end
   8,001,343,308 bytes allocated in the heap
     877,696,096 bytes copied during GC
          46,628 bytes maximum residency (861 sample(s))
          33,196 bytes maximum slop
            2 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

Generation 0: 14345 collections,     0 parallel,  3.32s,  3.38s elapsed
Generation 1:   861 collections,     0 parallel,  0.08s,  0.08s elapsed
```

The downside of using such strict transformers is that you can no longer define `MonadFix` instances and certain laziness tricks no longer work.

Comment: Wow, that is a very informative answer; and it works! I have yet to understand continuation monads but it's going to be much more pleasant learning now that I see it's practical use. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I think I was celebrating a bit too early. Your answer does answer my question nicely but unfortunately I'm still unable to solve the problem as a whole. That is, the MyStateT transformer threads the current offset nicely without noticable memory consumption but it creates another memory leak if I try to mix it whth another transformer to track child sizes. I've tried these approaches to do that: "type MyPut = MyStateT Offset (WriterT Size P.PutM)"  and  "newtype  MyPut = MyStateT { unS :: forall r . (Offset -> (a,Size) -> P.PutM r) -> Offset -> P.PutM r }". But no success.

Comment: I've started another (wider) question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157979/how-do-you-save-a-tree-data-structure-to-binary-file-in-haskell).

Comment: @Peter: Adding the non-cpsed monad probably kills the effects of the cpsed one. Given that state/writer is isomorphic to state, you can fold your writer information directly into the MyStateT.

Comment: @sclv, I'm not sure I get "state/writer is isomorphic" part, but I think I know what you mean. I thought about it as well and came up with this signature for the new Monad transformer: `newtype MyStateT m a = MyStateT { unMyStateT  :: forall r. (Offset -> (a,Size) -> m r) -> Offset -> m r }`. But I think I made a mistake back then in implementation, will try again and let you know. @nominolo, I forgot to notify you in my previous comment.

Comment: @Peter I just mean that you can write all the functions of writer using only the core functions of state (get and set) given a state for which you can treat some portion (e.g., the snd of a tuple) as a writer store.

Comment: The reason I defined it as an isomorphism is because I was making the slightly stronger claim that for any program written over `WriterT StateT ...` there is a mechanical translation to a program written over `StateT ...` and that there is also a translation the other way (which, in this case, is trivial).

Comment: @sclv, it does make sense but I'm having real problems extracting the size from such continuation state monad. I have updated my original question, if it's not too big of a problem, would you please create a new answer that explains how that can be done?

Answer (score 2):

I started playing with this and realized what the bigger problem is -- your algorithm has terrible complexity. Rather than computing the size of each child tree once, you compute it once for each time you call getSize. And you call getSize recursively. For each leaf node, getSize is called once for each time getSize is called on its parent. And getSize is called on each parent once for itself + once for each time getSize is called on any of *its* parents. So getsize is called at least geometrically in the depth of the tree. You need to cache the sizes to get something resembling a reasonable runtime.

That said, here's a version of the core functions that appears to run properly without a leak, although it's really crawling along for the reasons stated above:

```
type MyPut = S (Offset,Size) P.PutM

peal_1 :: (Monad m, Num t, Num t1) => S (t, t1) m a -> m a
peal_1 put = unS put (\o -> return) (0,0)

writeToFile :: String -> MyPut () -> IO ()
writeToFile path put =
  BL.writeFile path $ P.runPut $ (peal_1 put) >> return ()

getSize :: MyPut a -> MyPut Int
getSize x = S $ \f os -> unS (x >> getCurrentSize) f os

getCurrentOffset :: MyPut Int
getCurrentOffset = S $ \f os -> f os (fst os)

getCurrentSize :: MyPut Int
getCurrentSize = S $ \f os -> f os (snd os)
```

I also have to say I'm not sure if your logic is correct in general. My code preserves the current behavior while fixing the leak. I tested this by running it and your code on a cut-down data set and producing files that are bit-for-bit identical.

But for your large test data, this code wrote 6.5G before I killed it (the provided code exhausted heap well before then). I suspect but have not tested that the underlying calls in the put monad are getting run once for each call to getSize, even though the result of getSize is getting thrown away.

My proposed proper solution is posted as an answer to your other question: [How do you save a tree data structure to binary file in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157979/how-do-you-save-a-tree-data-structure-to-binary-file-in-haskell/5170082#5170082)

Comment: @sclv, first, thanks you for having a look at it. But I think you've done a simmilar mistake as I did when I said that some of my attemts end in infinite loops. The reson I think that is that if I use just _MyPut = S Offset P.PutM_ as the final monad and I fake getSize with _getSize _ = return 0_, the resulting file has only ~103MB (I think different sizes should not affect the output file size in this particular case).

Comment: @Peter -- I ran your provided code above on a smaller input set, and ran my code on the same input set. The resulting files were bit-for-bit identical. If there's a flaw in the logic, it's a flaw in the logic of both. And the flaw is precisely what I said -- getSize uses listen, which runs the action passed, and the action passed recursively puts data.

Comment: @Peter -- so, if you really want getSize to just give the size of the underlying tree and not to actually write it out, then just *do that* and you don't need any monads at all to do that. That's what my solution as posted on the other thread describes.

Comment: @sclv, hmm, I'm not sure we understand each other. Please have a look at [this](http://hpaste.org/44450/infinite_loop_in_cont_monad). If you set _FAKE_GETSIZE_ to _0_ then it will use your code and will write data possibly to infinity (not sure), but if you set it to _1_ then it will write 103MB output file and exit. I think doing two passes is a good solution in the context of the other question and I'm gratefull for that. Also, as many people like to repeat, one doesn't need monads, but it's also stressed that they help a lot.

Comment: @Peter. Precisely. Think about what getSize does. It is handed an action. It runs that action, then returns an int. When you use the real getsize, you run the action. When you use the fake getsize, you throw the action away without running it. In order for getSize to do anything meaningful, it *needs* to run the action. And running the action *means* writing data in the underlying Put monad. And that problem exists in your original code that I modified in exactly the same way it does in the code I provided. So, time for a new approach.

Comment: @sclv, true, but it feels like a defeat :-)