# What do ghc's FUN_1_0, FUN_0_1, etc closure types mean?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Closure types of `FUN_1_0`, `THUNK_1_0` etc often appear in heap profiles, but aren't documented anywhere. The undocumented types in `ghc-heap` correspond to [these constants](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/blob/master/includes/rts/storage/ClosureTypes.h), and there are some further clues in [`Layout.hs`](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/blob/a1f34d37b47826e86343e368a5c00f1a4b1f2bce/compiler/GHC/Runtime/Heap/Layout.hs) but it's still not clear what these mean.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019655/why-wrapping-the-data-binary-put-monad-creates-a-memory-leak-part-2/5020227#5020227) suggests `FUN_1_0` and `FUN_2_0` correspond to functions of one or two arguments, but that seems wrong (since there's no `FUN_3_0` for instance)

What do the various `FUN_` and `THUNK_` types mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variants `FUN_m_n` and `THUNK_m_n` are just special cases of `FUN` and `THUNK` meant to speed garbage collection.  (There's also a similar set of `CONSTR_m_n` special cases for `CONSTR`.)

A `FUN` heap object is a function closure.  A `THUNK` heap object is a suspended computation of an expression.  Both types of object potentially contain a *payload* of several word-sized fields giving the closed values for any free variables in the function body or thunk expression.  A `CONSTR` represents a saturated constructor, and its payload includes values for its fields.  The [Making a Fast Curry](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2016/07/eval-apply-icfp.pdf) paper has some useful background on this.

In the payloads for any of these closure types, some of those fields may be pointers (to boxed values) and some may be non-pointers (unboxed values appearing directly in the closure).  When the garbage collector is walking the heap, it needs to follow pointers and ignore non-pointers.  For all `FUN`s, `THUNK`s, and `CONSTR`s (whether special case `_m_n` types or general), their info tables have a bitmap that specifies how many fields are in the payload and which fields contain pointers.  However, there's a cost for the garbage collector to redirect to the info table and process the bitmap.

To speed garbage collection, a few special cases are defined with a different closure type, as `FUN_m_n`, etc., where `m` is the number of pointer fields, and `n` is the number of non-pointer fields.  For the variants `_0_1`, `_1_0`, `_2_0`, and `_0_2`, the garbage collector can immediately determine both the number of fields total and the fact that all are pointers (and so should be followed) or non-pointers (and so should be skipped), without redirecting to the info table bitmap.  For the `_1_1` variants, there's an ambiguity, since it's not clear which order the pointer and non-pointer appear in the payload, so the order pointer-then-non-pointer has been chosen.  If a closure has a non-pointer-then-pointer, it falls back to the general `FUN` or `THUNK` bitmap scheme.  You can see the algorithm at work in `rts/sm/Scav.c` function `scavenge_block`, which is one of the few pieces of code that actually treats the variants differently.