# How do you save a tree data structure to binary file in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree, monads, monad-transformers

I'm trying to save a simple (but quite big) Tree structure into a binary file using Haskell. The structure looks something like this:

```
-- For simplicity assume each Node has only 4 childs
data Tree = Node [Tree] | Leaf [Int]
```

And here is how I need the data look on disk:

1. Each node starts with four 32-bit offsets to it's children, then follow the childs.
2. I don't care much about the leafs, let's say it's just n consecutive 32-bit numbers.
3. For practival purposes I would need some node labels or some other additional data
   but right now I don't care about that much neither.

It apears to me that Haskellers first choice when writing binary files is the Data.Binary.Put library. But with that I have a problem in the bullet #1. In particular, when I'm about to write a Node to a file, to write down the child offsets I need to know my current offset and the size of each child.

This is not something that Data.Binary.Put provides so I thought this must be a perfect application of Monad transformers. But even though it sounds cool and functional, so far I have not been successfull with this approach.

I asked two other questions that I thought would help me solve the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828902/why-wrapping-the-data-binary-put-monad-creates-a-memory-leak) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019655/why-wrapping-the-data-binary-put-monad-creates-a-memory-leak-part-2). I must say that each time I received very nice answers that helped me progress further but unfortunatelly I am still unable to solve the problem as a whole.

[Here](http://hpaste.org/44419/how_do_you_save_a_tree_data_st) is what I've got so far, it still leaks too much memory to be practical.

I would love to have solution that uses such functional approach, but would be grateful for any other solution as well.

Comment: How big is the tree, and how large a file would you imagine that you'd be creating? The answer to this determines whether you can use any sort of put type structure at all, or if you need something that involves a single-pass traversal but modifying already written parts of your structure...

Comment: Binary serialization typically needs to know the size of the data to write (e.g. lists get prefixed with length). Could you live with text serialization (probably larger files)? Failing that you could do some tricks by writing to intermediate files and stitching them together (horrible but possible). 

Also in your test code the input is synthetic - if your real data isn't synthetic you might have it in memory anyway so normal binary serialization wouldn't be forcing anything that isn't already in the heap.

Comment: @sclv, the link "what I've got so far" above points to an extract of a bigger program I've been working on for some time now. In the original program I read a binary file with similar structure, transform it (mostly so that there isn't too many children per node) and then want to save it back. The source files have something between 50MB to 200MB so I imagine the destination files would be similar in size.

Comment: @stephen tetley, unfortunately the format has to stay as it is (there are some requirements on it that enforce that structure). I have about 4GB of memory on the development machine and I wouldn't mind having it spent on the data but I think there is something beyond my understanding that hogs the memory much more than is needed.

Comment: Does the tree already exist in memory?  Or is it being lazily computed on demand?  If the latter, then maybe your "leak" is the creation of the entire tree.

Comment: @Paul: I think creating the entire tree should not be a problem, if my calculations are correct, the tree in the example link above should take approximately _101 * 4^9 * sizeof(Int) + 1/3 * 4^9 * sizeof(Node) =~ 110MB_ assuming _sizeof(Int) = 4_ and _sizeof(Node) = 16_. Even if there was some overhead caused by e.g. GC it should still easily fit into my RAM (I think).

Comment: If the tree is large then serializing it will also create a large bytestring buffer on the heap - Data.Binary.Put cannot write "incrementally" to file. What you have is a tough problem as trees don't naturally stream - so a (naive) algorithm is going to need the whole tree in memory. No doubt there is a classic algorithmic solution to re-balancing a tree without loading it all into memory, but I'm afraid I don't know it.

Comment: A list of Ints requires 8 or 12 bytes per element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is implementation of two pass solution proposed by **sclv**.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.Binary.Put
import Data.Word
import Data.List (foldl')

data Tree = Node [Tree] | Leaf [Word32] deriving Show

makeTree 0 = Leaf $ replicate 100 0xdeadbeef
makeTree n = Node $ replicate 4 $ makeTree $ n-1
```

SizeTree mimics original Tree, it does not contain data but at each node it stores size of corresponding child in Tree.
We need to have SizeTree in memory, so it worth to make it more compact (e.g. replace Ints with uboxed words).

```
data SizeTree
  = SNode {sz :: Int, chld :: [SizeTree]}
  | SLeaf {sz :: Int}
  deriving Show
```

With SizeTree in memory it is possible to serialize original Tree in streaming fashion.

```
putTree :: Tree -> SizeTree -> Put
putTree (Node xs) (SNode _ ys) = do
  putWord8 $ fromIntegral $ length xs          -- number of children
  mapM_ (putWord32be . fromIntegral . sz) ys   -- sizes of children
  sequence_ [putTree x y | (x,y) <- zip xs ys] -- children data
putTree (Leaf xs) _ = do
  putWord8 0                                   -- zero means 'leaf'
  putWord32be $ fromIntegral $ length xs       -- data length
  mapM_ putWord32be xs                         -- leaf data


mkSizeTree :: Tree -> SizeTree
mkSizeTree (Leaf xs) = SLeaf (1 + 4 + 4 * length xs)
mkSizeTree (Node xs) = SNode (1 + 4 * length xs + sum' (map sz ys)) ys
  where
    ys = map mkSizeTree xs
    sum' = foldl' (+) 0
```

It is important to prevent GHC from merging two passes into one (in which case it will hold tree in memory).
Here it is done by feeding not tree but tree generator to the function.

```
serialize mkTree size = runPut $ putTree (mkTree size) treeSize
  where
    treeSize = mkSizeTree $ mkTree size

main = L.writeFile "dump.bin" $ serialize makeTree 10
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic approaches I would consider.  If the entire serialized structure will easily fit into memory, you can serialize each node into a lazy bytestring and just use the lengths for each of them to calculate the offset from the current position.

```
serializeTree (Leaf nums)  = runPut (mapM_ putInt32 nums)
serializeTree (Node subtrees) = mconcat $ header : childBs
 where
  childBs = map serializeTree subtrees
  offsets = scanl (\acc bs -> acc+L.length bs) (fromIntegral $ 2*length subtrees) childBs
  header = runPut (mapM_ putInt32 $ init offsets)
```

The other option is, after serializing a node, go back and re-write the offset fields with the appropriate data.  This may be the only option if the tree is large, but I don't know of a serialization library that supports this.  It would involve working in `IO` and `seek`ing to the correct locations.

Answer (score 2):

What I think you want is an explicit two pass solution. The first converts your tree into a size annotated tree. This pass forces the tree, but can be done, in fact, without any monadic machinery at all by tying the knot. The second pass is in the plain old Put monad, and given that the size annotations are already calculated, should be very straightforward.

Comment: this would work, however I think my solution would be more memory efficient.  This is because my approach will allow each sub-tree to be collected after it's serialized, and the bytestring serialization should be much smaller than the actual tree.

Comment: @John -- you're probably right. Your solution is genuinely one pass, but just not fully streaming.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation using [Builder](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/0.5.0.1/doc/html/Data-Binary-Builder.html), which is part of the "binary" package.  I haven't profiled it properly, but according to "top" it immediately allocates 108 Mbytes and then hangs on to that for the rest of the execution.

Note that I haven't tried reading the data back, so there may be lurking errors in my size and offset calculations.

```
-- Paste this into TreeBinary.hs, and compile with
--    ghc -O2 --make TreeBinary.hs -o TreeBinary

module Main where


import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.Binary.Builder as B

import Data.List (init)
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Word


-- -------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Test data.

data Tree = Node [Tree] | Leaf [Word32] deriving Show

-- Approximate size in memory (ignoring laziness) I think is:
-- 101 * 4^9 * sizeof(Int) + 1/3 * 4^9 * sizeof(Node)

-- This version uses [Word32] instead of [Int] to avoid having to write
-- a builder for Int.  This is an example of lazy programming instead
-- of lazy evaluation. 

makeTree :: Tree
makeTree = makeTree1 9
  where makeTree1 0 = Leaf [0..100]
        makeTree1 n = Node [ makeTree1 $ n - 1
                           , makeTree1 $ n - 1
                           , makeTree1 $ n - 1
                           , makeTree1 $ n - 1 ]

-- --------------------------------------------------------------------
-- The actual serialisation code.


-- | Given a tree, return a builder for it and its estimated length in bytes.
serialiseTree :: Tree -> (B.Builder, Word32)
serialiseTree (Leaf ns) = (mconcat (B.singleton 2 : map B.putWord32be ns), fromIntegral $ 4 * length ns + 1)
serialiseTree (Node ts) = (mconcat (B.singleton 1 : map B.putWord32be offsets ++ branches), 
                           baseLength + sum subLengths)
   where
      (branches, subLengths) = unzip $ map serialiseTree ts
      baseLength = fromIntegral $ 1 + 4 * length ts
      offsets = init $ scanl (+) baseLength subLengths


main = do
   putStrLn $ "Length = " ++ show (snd $ serialiseTree makeTree)
   BL.writeFile "test.bin" $ B.toLazyByteString $ fst $ serialiseTree makeTree
```